# How do I show that $\alpha$ is not an element of $F(\beta)$

Tags: polynomials, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

[image]

I am trying to show that $\alpha$ is not an element of $F(\beta)$:

My attempt was by contradiction suppose $\alpha \in F(\beta)$

Then $\alpha = h(\beta) $ where $h$ is a polynomial in $F[x]$

Then $h(\beta)^p=t$

However, I'm stuck at this point.

I need the above to show that $x^p -t$ is irreducible in $F(\beta)$

Comment: Hint: Have you used the independence of $u$ and $t$ yet?

Comment: I know you would get a function g(u)=t where g is in F[x]. But what if g(u) is of the form t?

Comment: Then $t$ is not algebraically independent from $u$.

Comment: as in what if g(x) is t itself. Then would g(u)=t but that does not mean that t is algebraically independent right?

Comment: Algebraically independence means that there are *no* nontrivial polynomial relationships between $u$ and $t$.  $g(u)-t$ is a polynomial relationship between $u$ and $t$.